# RegExp / JavaScript: Split string on multiple characters, keep separators without using lookbehind

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, split

Let's say I have a string: `"This is a string-thing"`. I want to split on both space and hyphen, but keep the separators together with the previous word => `["This ", "is ", "a ", "string-", "thing"]`

I'm currently doing this using the following regExp:

```
string.split(/(?<=[\s-])/g)
```

This does what is supposed to.. at least in Chrome. As I understand Safari doesn't support lookbehind in regExp which breaks the code. Is there any way to do this without lookbehind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match the words without lookbehind.

```js
const
    string = "This is a string-thing",
    parts = string.match(/.+?([\s-]|$)/g);

console.log(parts);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also use split with a capture group to keep the value to split on, and remove the empty entries from the resulting array.

The pattern matches

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\s-]*` Repeat 0+ times matching any char other than a whitespace char or `-`
  - `[\s-]` Match either a whitespace char or `-`
- `)` Close group 1

Note that `\s` can also match a newline.

```js
const s = "This is a string-thing";
const regex = /([^\s-]*[\s-])/;
console.log(s.split(regex).filter(Boolean));
```